# Flutter Firebase Authentication With Google SignIn

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter, gradle, google-signin

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_auth'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':firebase_auth:classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.5/gradle-6.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.5/gradle-6.5.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/Unzilla/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.5/gradle-6.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :firebase_auth
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_auth' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code
```

I am trying to create  firebase authentication using google signin method but getting this error after running my app. I've added my app in firebase console and also enabled google signin and also have done required configurations but stuck in this error for a week.Anyone knows how to solve this?I have also added SHA-1 key in firebase console.Seems like there is issue in firebase_auth package.

pubspec.yaml

```
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
  google_sign_in:
  firebase_auth:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

app level build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_google"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    compile platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
}
```

project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
void main(){
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: "Authentication",
    home: ExampleGoogle(),
  ));
}
class ExampleGoogle extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return ExampleState();
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth =FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn =GoogleSignIn();
  class ExampleState extends State<ExampleGoogle> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      // TODO: implement build
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Firebase Example"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
                _signIn();
              },
                child: Text("Sign Up"),
                color: Colors.black,
                textColor: Colors.white,

              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
      throw UnimplementedError();
    }

    _signIn() async {
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn
          .signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount
          .authentication;
      final AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,

        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,


      );
      User user = (await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential))
          .user;
    }
  }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your `google-services.json` file?
The followings are wrong formatted:

`google-services(1).json`
`google-services .json`

Comment: I've added ```google-services.json``` inside app folder

Comment: I am asking if the folder name is not typed correctly. Like the followings above. Sometimes, it happens to me if you download the same file twice. File name changes lik `file_name(1).extension`. So be careful with that, the name of your file must be exactly  `google-services.json`

Comment: Yeah @Demir I checked file name is typed correctly.